# Extract each level data with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

The following is the JSon data.

```
{
        "statusType": "OK",
        "entity": [
            {
            "category": "category1","difficultyLevel": "Easy",
            "quizAnswerChoices": [{"choiceText": "Yes", "choiceTextHash": "c3f1130841b507a4d1e0f45971d990c6ecd25406"}, {"choiceText": "Yes", "choiceTextHash": "c3f1130841b507a4d1e0f45971d990c6ecd25406"}]
            }
        ],
        "entityType": "java.util.ArrayList",
        "status": 200,
        "metadata": {}
    }
```

I need to parse
- entity
- quizAnswerChoices (count the item)

How to retrieve each `choiceText` etc

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: [json_decode($json)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn the json data into a PHP array, then go from there. EG: `count($arrayname['entity']['quizAnswerChoices'])`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$json='{
        "statusType": "OK",
        "entity": [
            {
            "category": "category1","difficultyLevel": "Easy",
            "quizAnswerChoices": [{"choiceText": "Yes", "choiceTextHash": "c3f1130841b507a4d1e0f45971d990c6ecd25406"}, {"choiceText": "Yes", "choiceTextHash": "c3f1130841b507a4d1e0f45971d990c6ecd25406"}]
            }
        ],
        "entityType": "java.util.ArrayList",
        "status": 200,
        "metadata": {}
    }';
$encodedJson= json_decode($json,true);
$quizAnswerChoices=$encodedJson['entity'][0]['quizAnswerChoices'];
echo 'Count: '.count($quizAnswerChoices);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$arry = json_decode($json,true);


 foreach ($arry['entity'] as $ke => $ve) {
       foreach ($ve['quizAnswerChoices'] as $k => $v) {
         print_r($v);
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a json_decode like

```
$data = json_decode(json_data);
```

Then $data will be a traversable array

```
$data['entity']['quizAnswerChoices'] etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider you are recieving this json in a variable called `"$contents"`.
All you have to do is decode it:

```
$decoded = json_decode($contents, true); //True so, the decoded object will be converted into an ssociative array

print_r($decoded);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `json_decode` to convert json to array

```
$dataArray = json_decode($json_string, true)
$dataArray['entity']; // entity
$dataArray['entity']['quizAnswerChoices']; // quizAnswerChoices
$dataArray['entity']['quizAnswerChoices']; // quizAnswerChoices
count($dataArray['entity']['quizAnswerChoices']); // quizAnswerChoices count
```